# Why do we use 2 bits at the start of a floating point number?

Tags: floating-point, standards

So normalized floating point numbers are always stored with the leading digits as 10 or 01, why do we store this with 2 separate digits if it will only ever take one of two states which could be represented with one bit?

Comment: Which floating point format are you referring to exactly? In a 32-bit IEEE float (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#See_also) the first two bits are the sign and the most significant bit of the exponent.

Comment: I guess you should specify which "first bits" you mean. The top bits? The top bits of th significand? Something else? I don't know a format that has normalized numbers that start with top bits 01 or 10, not for the entire FP, not for the significand.

Comment: Maybe the OP is asking about the first (i.e., most significant) two bits of the exponent, which would tend to be either `10` or `01` for values that aren't at the extremes of the exponent range. But that certainly wouldn't count as "always". It's hard to tell what the real question is here, and I suspect that it's based on a misunderstanding by the OP. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @Rudy I meant the first two bits of the mantissa/fraction I thought the standard was to have that first anyway sorry for confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding both the Single-precision (32-bit) or the Double-precision (64-bit) that are the most common standards, none of them uses those two first bits always in the exact combination you mentioned. It depends on the number.

In both the first bit stores the sign of the number which can have both 0 and 1 values, while the next bit is the most significant bit of the exponent which can also have 0 or 1 value depending on the exact number.

To illustrate the usage of those bits here are the patterns of the floating point numbers structure:

**- Single-precision:**

[image: Single-precision structure]

**- Double-precision:**

[image: Double-precision structure]

Check out some info about floating point numbers: [Single-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#See_also) and [Double-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Answer (score 1):

I dont see this encoding on IEEE-754, single precision. The first bit represents the sign and it is possible to set both of the first bits. This can be seen with this code -

```
int main()
{
    float value=-100.5;
    int *valueptr;
    valueptr = &value;
    printf("%0.3f, %08x\n",value, *valueptr);
    value=100.5;
    printf("%0.3f, %08x\n",value, *valueptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `valueptr = &value` followed by `*valueptr` violates C rules about aliasing objects. Although many C implementations support this to some extent, it is preferable to do this in a way supported by the C standard: Either copy the bytes of the object (`unsigned x; memcpy(&x, &value, sizeof x);`) or reinterpret the bytes through a union (`(union { float f; unsigned u; }) {value} .u`). Also note that the `x` conversion specifier is for `unsigned int` rather than `int`.